# NLog - Save ${message} in multiple database columns

Tags: c#, nlog

I'd like to save the logged message `${message}` in several columns in a database, as shown on the following example:

My logger messages will follow the path `User|Action`, e.g:

```
logger.Info("John Doe|Logged in application"}  
logger.Info("Mike Doe|Deleted a file"}
```

Now I'd like to save `User` in a column in my database, e.g `logsTable.user`, and `Action` in another column, e.g `logsTable.action`.

Is there any way to parse the `${message}` with a regex or some other rules (to separate messages according to a specific character, in my example it's a "`|`") to save into parameters (in my case, i'd like the first part of the message to go in `@user` parameter and the second part in `@action` parameter)?

Comment: are you asking for an sql query that parses the message? then add the sql tag to your question. or are you asking for a bit of C# that parses a log string and outputs the 2 result strings?

Comment: @mtijn Your second thought. I'd like to parse the `${message}` text to output one part in a parameter and the other part in another parameter. But this has to be done in the _NLog.config_ file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [NLog documentation](http://nlog-project.org/wiki/.NET_logging_API) it shouldn't be too complicated to add your own properties to a log event. Then you could do an extension method on the correct NLog interface and write something like this (uncompiled):

```
public void LogSomething(this ILog logger, string username, string message)
{
  LogEventInfo myEvent = new LogEventInfo(LogLevel.Debug, "", message);
  myEvent.LoggerName = logger.Name;
  myEvent.Properties.Add("User", username);
  logger.Log(myEvent);
}
```

Now you should be able to refer to `${event-context:item=User}`

Comment: Works great. Just one error in your answer : I have to refer to `${event-context:item=User}` in my _NLog.config_ file. See _http://nlog-project.org/wiki/Event-context_layout_renderer_ for more details.

Comment: Links in answer and comment above are broken.